# What is the correct syntax for using gdb with termux-usb?

Tags: android, c, gdb, libusb, termux

I am writing a program in C using the libusb library, to enable an Android phone to communicate with a USB device.

The C program runs in the termux emulator on the phone. It uses termux-usb to make the usb device visible to the C program as follows:

```
>termux-usb -l
>termux-usb -r /dev/bus/usb/001/002
>termux-usb -e ./program /dev/bus/usb/001/002
```

What is the correct syntax to use if I want to run and debug the program using gdb together with termux-usb?

I've tried all kinds of combinations of gdb --args and termux-usb -e, but none recognize the /dev/bus/usb/001/002 argument.

Comment: Is there a physical device connected to the Android phone before running `termux-usb`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe: gdb | termux-usb or termux-usb | gdb
like, If you run curl with just url and no args, it will write to terminal, but If you run curl [url] | cat < a, it will write to the file "a"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).